# Solidworks/VB.NET SaveBMP() Not Saving Bitmap Consistently

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, solidworks

I have a VB.NET program that redimensions parts and assemblies in Solidworks and then shows the image of the assembly drawing in a panel using SaveBMP(). My issue is not showing the image - it is that whenever the user moves the location of a dimension in the Solidworks drawing, the entire location and size of the Bitmap changes and I need to go into my code to readjust my crop and resize values.

Saving drawing as bitmap image:

```
      swModel.SaveBMP(BMPName, 1700, 1100) '17x11 aspect ratio
```

Cropping my image to remove white space:

```
  Function CropDrawing(ByVal OldImage As Image) As Image
    CropDrawing = Nothing
    Dim X As Integer = GetValue(frmImageScale.txtCropX.Text)
    Dim Y As Integer = GetValue(frmImageScale.txtCropY.Text)
    Dim Width As Integer = GetValue(GetValue(frmImageScale.txtCropW.Text))
    Dim Height As Integer = GetValue(frmImageScale.txtCropH.Text)
    Dim CropRect As New Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height)
    Try
        Dim CropImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height)
        Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(CropImage)
            grp.DrawImage(OldImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, CropImage.Width, CropImage.Height), CropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            OldImage.Dispose()
            'resave
            CropImage.Save(BMPName)
        End Using
        Return CropImage
    Catch ex As Exception
        'caught if width and height = 0
    End Try
End Function
```

Resizing image to fit panel:

```
Public Function ResizeImage(ByVal OldImage As Image, ByVal TargetWidth As Integer, ByVal TargetHeight As Integer) As System.Drawing.Image
    Return New Bitmap(OldImage, TargetWidth, TargetHeight)
End Function
```

Once the bitmap is created, I crop the image and then I resize it to fill the panel.

Any suggestions on why this is happening are appreciated!